# How to make a raster in the background of a panel/tabPane/s.e

Tags: c++, qt, background, grid, raster

I try to create something, where you can drop different things on it, like the Qt Creator (no, i don't want to create a new one, but i need the function of that).
You drag some elements and drop them anywhere in a tabPane.
My problem now is how to make a grid/raster in the background. 
It should look similar to this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOA4K.png]

I mean those dots in the background.
If I make them with two for loops, it will take hours and it's not efficient or anything else.
There has to be a more efficient solution and a lot easier one.

I'm programming in c++ with Qt as a Framework. Please give me some links or anything else I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- limit the repainting to region that really needs to be updated as explained in [`QWidget::paintEvent` documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#paintEvent),
- fill a container of `QPoint` in your loops instead of drawing the points, and draw them all with `QPainter::drawPoints` after the loop,
- cache the result in a `QPixmap` with transparency and reuse it if the window size didn't change ([example from Qt Quaterly](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq12-qpixmapcache.html)).

Of course, you should do some testing to see if you gain anything at all by doing any of these optimizations.